# Show that some sets are closed, open, convex, but not dense

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

> Let $X = C[a,b]$, where $-\infty < a < b < \infty$ and $\|u\| = \max_{x \in [a,b]}|u(x)|$. Set
>   $$(a) \ \  U = \{u \in X |u(a) = 1\}, (a) \ \  V = \{u \in X |u(a) > 0\}.$$
>   Show that $U$ is closed, convex, not dense subset of $X$ and that $V$ is open,convex, not dense subset of $X$.

To show that $U$ is closed, it is enough to show that if $u_n \to u$ as $n \to \infty$, for $u_n \in U$, then $u \in U$, but $u \in U$ means that $u(a) = 1$. Now, by definition, we have that $u_n(a) = 1$ for each $n$ and that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n = u,$$
which follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty}u_n(a) = 1$ and thus $u(a) = 1$ as required. Thus, $u \in U$ and therefore $U$ is closed. To show that is convex, we have to show that for any $u,v \in U$ and $r \in [0,1]$, then
$$ru + (1-r)v \in U,$$
which is sufficient to prove that $$ru(a) + (1-r)v(a) = 1.$$
But, since $u,v \in U$, then $u(a) = v(a) = 1$ and therefore, the previous equation becomes
$$r + (1-r) = 1,$$
so we have proved that $U$ is convex. On the other hand to show that $V$ is open it is enough to show that $V^c$ is closed, where 
$$V^c = \{v \in X | v(a) \leq 0\}.$$ Using a similar reasoning as before, we want to show that if if $u_n \to u$ as $n \to \infty$, for $u_n \in V^c$, then $u \in V^c$, but $u \in V^c$ means that $u(a) \leq 0$. By definition, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} u_n = u,$$
and for each $n$, we have $u_n(a),$ thus $\lim_{n \to \infty} u(n) \leq 0$, so that $u(a) \leq 0$ as required. To show that is convex, let $u,v \in V$ and $r \in[0,1]$. Then the inequality
$$r u(a) + (1-r) v(a) > 0,$$
holds because $u,v \in V$ and $r \in [0,1]$. Now, in class, we have not discussed the concept of density, can someone tell me the definition when something is not dense (using set theory if possible)? Also, is this argument right so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition**: A set $A$ is dense in $X$ if $\bar{A} = X$. In some sense, $A$ is *big enough* in X. In the simple case of $X$ being a **metric space**, that amounts to: every $x \in X$ is the limit of a sequence $x_n \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$.

(a) $U$ is closed, hence we have $\bar{U} = U$. Clearly, one has $X \neq U$, therefore one concludes that $U$ cannot be dense in $X$

(b) Let $h \in X := C([a,b])$, such that $h(a)=\eta$, with $\eta < 0$. Let us show that there exists no sequence of functions in $V$ such that the limit is $h$. Suppose such a sequence $(f_n)_n$ exists.

Since $||f_n - h|| \rightarrow_n 0$
we have $\max_{x\in [a,b]} |f_n(x) - h(x)| \rightarrow_n 0$, which means that $|f_n(a) -  h(a)| \rightarrow 0$. Because $f_n \in V$, one has $f_n(a) > 0$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But $h(a) = \eta < 0$, so that $|f_n(a) - h(a)| > \eta$ for all $n$, therefore leading to a contradiction.

Comment: For (b) this shows that $V$ is open or that $V$ is not dense?

Comment: This shows that $V$ is not dense. You've already proved that $V$ is open, by proving that $V^c$ is closed. By the very definition of a dense subset, $V$ cannot be dense. Otherwise, every function $f$ in $X$ need to be the limit of a sequence of functions $f_n \in V$, which is impossible by the argument above.